# .Net 6 Windows Forms Designer deletes own user controls

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I transferred an application from .net fw 4.8 to .net 6. A form contains some simple own UserControls (only containing 2 labels each). When I open the designer the controls are not being displayed anymore. When I run the application the controls are being displayed properly. When I make some change to the form (e.g. changing any property value), the designer deletes all of the custom user controls. How can I prevent him from doing this? What can I do to make the user controls to be visible in designer again ?

Comment: 1. I deleted all the content in the `.csproj` file and replaced it with .net6 2. The "Properties" folder and files in the project 3. Reload the project 4. Add dependencies according to the error prompt 5. The design page does not appear, run OK 6. Compile after commenting out the error code, and uncomment and compile again. The design page is intact.

Comment: I did not encounter your problem, please try to update the error you are encountering. Retry the operation.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my post. Meanwhile I was able to solve the problem by moving the UserControl to another assemly. Maybe it is "recommended practice" and I din't know about it...

Comment: Hi Tomsaw, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by moving the UserControl to another assembly than the one that contained the form. The designer saw an "outdated" version of the UserControl and could not use it.

Answer (score 0):

What "Visual Studio" version you use?
For VS 2022 (Preview): Check "Options > Environment > Preview Features" -
"Use the preview Windows Forms out-of-process designer for .NET Framework apps (requires restart)"

Uncheck it, Restart VS and check your Forms/UserControls again.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue, my own user controls were removed whenever I edited the main form. In my case I was able to resolve the issue by using a guard in my user controls' constructors:

```
if (DesignMode) { return; }
```

Another user in a MS forum did solve the issue by changing his classes from `internal` to `public`.

Check this thread as well: [How do I keep Visual Studio's Windows Forms Designer from deleting controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2677646/356726)